# In Scala, is it possible to have a case class containing methods with identical names to fields?

Tags: scala

I think I'd like to be able to do something like the following (clearly garbage) code illustrates:

```
// Clearly nonsensical
case class Example(a: String) {
    def a: Array[Byte] = a.getBytes
}
```

The gist of it is that I want to write an accessor method for a case class that is named identically to one of its constructor arguments.

I'm using a JSON serialization library called [Jerkson](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson) that, according to my understanding, will behave in the way I want it to if I define a class in this manner. I'm basing that assumption on [this code](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/codahale/jerkson/ser/CaseClassSerializer.scala#L23-L38). Currently, I'm [stumped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102550/use-the-non-default-constructor-with-jerkson).

If this isn't possible, could anyone offer some insight on what the Jerkson library code is attempting to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala automatically creates a method with the same name as any `val` declared in a class (including the fields of case classes) to support a concept called [referential transparency](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/glossary.html#g-1825668081). This is also why you can [override a `def` with a `val`](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/abstract-members.html#lst%3abad-apple). If you're still skeptical, you can test it yourself like this:

First, create a Scala file with a single case class.

```
// MyCase.scala
case class MyCase(myField1: Int, myField2: String)
```

Now, compile the file with `scalac`. This should result in two classes. For the example above I get *MyCase.class* (representing the actual case class type) and *MyCase$.class* (representing the auto-generated companion object for the case class).

```
$ scalac MyCase.scala 
$ ls
MyCase$.class MyCase.class  MyCase.scala
```

Now you can examine the resulting `.class` file corresponding to the case class you declared using `javap`. (`javap` standard tool for examining Java bytecode—it's distributed along with `javac` in the JDK.)

```
$ javap -private MyCase
Compiled from "MyCase.scala"
public class MyCase extends java.lang.Object implements scala.Product,scala.Serializable{
    private final int myField1;
    private final java.lang.String myField2;
    public static final scala.Function1 tupled();
    public static final scala.Function1 curry();
    public static final scala.Function1 curried();
    public scala.collection.Iterator productIterator();
    public scala.collection.Iterator productElements();
    public int myField1();
    public java.lang.String myField2();
    public MyCase copy(int, java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String copy$default$2();
    public int copy$default$1();
    public int hashCode();
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public java.lang.String productPrefix();
    public int productArity();
    public java.lang.Object productElement(int);
    public boolean canEqual(java.lang.Object);
    private final boolean gd1$1(int, java.lang.String);
    public MyCase(int, java.lang.String);
}
```

Notice how the resulting class has both a `private final int myField1` and a `public int myField1()` corresponding to the case class's `myField1` field. The same for `myField2`.

On the JVM method return types are *not* part of the method signature. This means that if two methods have the same name and the same argument types then they're considered to be conflicting method declarations. This means you can't declare the `def a: Array[Byte]` in your example because `val a: String` already exists, also taking no arguments.

***Update:***

I just looked at the library code and according to the examples the case classes should just work. There *is* a note in the README saying that parsing case classes *does not work in the REPL.* Could that be your problem? If not, you should really post the error you're getting. **Edit:** Never mind, I see the error you're talking about in your link to your other post. If I think of a response to that problem I'll post it over there.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. The reason is that constructor arguments of `case` classes are automatically public values, like if you declare them with `val`. To quote [A Tour of Scala: Case Classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/107)

> The constructor parameters of case classes are treated as public values and can be accessed directly.

Therefore, for each constructor argument Scala creates a corresponding [accessor method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Accessor_and_mutator_methods) with the same name. You cannot create a method with the same name, it's already there.

This is actually what `case` classes are about. The idea is that they can be used for pattern matching, so the values retrieved from them should be the same as the values used to construct them.

(Is it a requirement that you use `case` classes? Using regular classes seems to solve the problem.)